# Extract text from column in select of MySql query

Tags: mysql, locate

I have a table named `sentEmails` where the `body` column contains the body text of an email.

In the body text, there is a substring like:

`some link: <a href="https://somelink@somesite.com/somePage.php?someVar=someVal&sentby=agent">Random link text`

Using MySql, I need to extract the url from this column like `https://somelink@somesite.com/somePage.php?someVar=someVal&sentby=agent`

I was thinking something like the below would work by finding the starting location and returning the next 150 chars, of course it actually just returns the first 150 chars.

```
SELECT LEFT(body, LOCATE('some link: <a href="', body)+150)  AS link
FROM sentEmails
WHERE sent between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now()
AND body like '%some link:%'
AND toEmail = 'email@gmail.com'
```

Additional info:

- the link will always be preceded by the text `some link:`
- `Random link text` at the end will change
- I can live with getting a bit more of the text than need if I have to, for example, getting `https://somelink@somesite.com/somePage.php">Random link text` would be acceptable
- the text shown above is a *substring* of the full `body` column which contains much more text
- This isnt something Im going to be doing often. Im researching an issue and I need the links from 40-50 of these rows, Im just hoping to avoid having to pull the link manually from each row.
- **I can only use MySQL Query Browser to access this DB** if I could connect with php, this would be trivial
- The url in question, can have 6-25 parameters in it
- The url in question will always end with this parameter `&sentby=agent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had two unique delimiters around the URL, then could just use `SUBSTRING()` to isolate it.  One approach would be to replace the two sides of the URL in the anchor tag with a delimeter:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(body, '<a href="', '~'), '&sentby=agent">', '&sentby=agent~'), '~', -2),
    '~', 1)
FROM sentEmails
WHERE sent BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW() AND
    body LIKE '%some link:%' AND
    toEmail = 'email@gmail.com'
```

I replaced `<a href="` and `">` with `~`.  If `~` does not occur anywhere in the `body` column, and if you only have one HTML tag in the body, then this should work.

If the `body` column is just a big chunk of HTML, then you should consider using xpath and handling this in your app layer.

Comment: What if there are other quotes not around links? Like classes or any other occurence?

Comment: This is really close, but as Nico points out, the content does indeed have other "s. I tried updating this to `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(body, 'some link: <a href="', -2), '"', 1)` but it returns that beginning of the string up to the first `"` as if  `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is returning 0 which I really dont understand because the text is definitely there and HAS TO BE THERE since `AND body like '%some link:%'` is in the query

Comment: Unfortunately, the body column is indeed just a big chunk of HTML. This isnt something Im going to be doing often. Im researching an issue and I need the links from 40-50 of these rows, Im just hoping to avoid having to pull the link manually from each row. Actually, I just checked to be sure and the url will always end with `&sentby=agent`

Comment: You should be using an XML parser for this, rather than the string functions of MySQL.  Nevertheless, I updated my answer again and you can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I updated the question to also state that I am only allowed to use MySQL Query Browser to access this DB. I didnt think that  was relevant since the SQL is all still the same but given the points about better ways this should be done, I see it is an important detail. Im home for the night but Ill try your update tomorrow and let you know. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

if you're just trying to extract the link out, can you do instr() and mid function.  something like this

```
select mid(body,substr(body,'="'),substr(body,'">')-substr(body,'="')) from email...
```

substr(body,'="') = starting position of the link =" and substr(body,'">') is the end position of the link.

MID function takes (str,pos, len) and len = end position - starting position

Comment: Its a bit more complicated than that since the link is buried in a large mound of html that includes numerous other links and the link in question itself can have various other parameters

Comment: give us a real example of what it looks like and what the results should look like.

Comment: Updated the question. The only difference is that there are query strings on the url and one plus is that I confirmed the URLs will always end with `sentby=agent`

Comment: I'm sorry, a little confuse, you know what it preceded by and ended with.  will some text: and sentby=agent appear more than 1?

Comment: No, that bit will only ever occur once. If I could use a regex, I'd know how to do it, but from what I found, regex won't work in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim's help, I was able to get this working with the below query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(body, 'some link:  <a href="', -1) , 'sentby=agent">', 1) AS link
FROM sentEmails
where sent between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now()
AND body like '%some link:%'
AND toEmail = 'email@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score -2):

Doing this kind of search is not convenient. As the table with emails grows in size, the query will be less and less performant.

If this is a new application you're building, you're better with keeping a separate table with the list of URLs used on each sent email. You'd write the URLs to the DB as you send the emails.

The reasoning of this is that the App will do more searches in the DB than sending emails. Therefore, by doing a little extra work when sending emails, you help a lot in the most-expensive usage of the feature, which is the search.

If you still decide to keep the current approach, you'll want to have an index containing the columns (toEmail, sent) in this order.

Other than that, your approach makes sense and will work. Did you actually try it? Does it work for you?

Comment: I did try it but it just returns the first 150 chars. You make valid points. But this isnt something Im going to be doing often and wont end up in any production code. Im researching an issue and I need the links from 40-50 of these rows, Im just hoping to avoid having to pull the link manually from each row as they hold a ton of text and I can only use MySql Browser to access the DB. If I could connect with php, this would all be trivial

Comment: You'll have another issue. This query will return only 1 match per email. In case you have more than one link per email, you won't get the 2nd one.

Comment: Thanks, there is only one target link in each email